# Change the color of the three bars of the sandwich bootstrap menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't change the color of the three bars of the sandwich menu in bootstrap 5.

I was able to change the background color and remove the outer border.

So I'm pointing to the right element.

If someone has an idea.

Comment: Please also add a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

For the hamburger menu, an image is used as the background for the navbar-toggler-icon class

If needed, you should add a new image to this class as a menu.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).